# How do I hide a menu item from unauthenticated Users in Plone/Zope

Tags: plone, zope

In the Top navigation bar there is a button called 'Users'. I would like to hide that button from people who are not logged in to the site, so that it physically doesn't appear in the menu. Is there any way this can be done?

I am using Plone 4.

Answer (score 5):

If you have not enabled user folders (site setup / security), then you don't need the "Users" folder at all. Delete it.

If you do have user folders enabled, but don't want to show the Users folder to unauthenticated users, then set the folder's state to "private", then use the share tab to give logged-in users the "Can view" role.

If you have a substantial number of site users and you wish to show/hide content based on authentication, you may wish to enable the Intranet/Extranet workflow, which will give you more sharing options.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the link to the "Members" folder (http://.../Members) you can just hide this folder (change it's state to private).
Or: delete it, I don't know anybody that still use it today!

If you need to keep it visibile, a new CSS rules can help:

```
#portaltab-Members {display: none}
```